# How to color a grid row conditionally in Vaadin 8?

Tags: java, sass, vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin8

I want to change the color of a Vaadin grid row based on a value of a cell. I tried it as follows and did not work.

**SCSS**

```
@import "mytheme.scss";
@import "addons.scss";

// This file prefixes all rules with the theme name to avoid causing conflicts with other themes.
// The actual styles should be defined in mytheme.scss

.mytheme {
     @include addons;
     @include mytheme;

     .v-grid-row.error_row {
            // Tried following elements and didn't work.
            // background-color: red !important;
            // color: blue !important; // This changed the color of the font.
            background: green !important;
     }
}
```

**Java Code**

```
grid.setStyleGenerator(t -> {
            if (t.getLogLevel().trim().equals(ERROR) || t.getLogLevel().trim().equals(WARN)) {
                return "error_row";
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Note: I check the css from the browser's developer tools and that shows the css is updated properly (See the below image).

[image]

Comment: I expected to see in java code xxx.addStylename("howitscalled");

Comment: I mean you only set how lines will be presented in a grid row. But WHAT color they will be represented - thats another question.

Comment: I wonder why you have .mytheme nested into .mytheme in your SCSS?

Comment: @Reborn - I just want to change the background color of the row and I have specified the color in the styles.scss file.

Comment: Maybe the background-color style is overwritten by cell's td style? Did you inspect the styles of a cell?

Comment: I'd recommend you to make additional css style for row backgorund and in java code after checkin condition use `xxx.setStyleName("myGridColorName")` and in addition use `xxx.addStyleName` to label, so it would not conflict (if any)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to overwrite the `background-color` of the row's TD element:

```
.v-grid-row.error_row > td {
    background-color: red;
}
```

By using your browser's style inspection you can see how Vaadin has implemented styles.

Comment: Sorry my bad, that solution works fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Indeed, this solution works for me too in Vaadin 8.6.0.beta1. Thank you.

Comment: Variation… To color only the second column, use [`nth-child`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/) selector:  `.v-grid-row.fresh_row > td:nth-child(2) { background-color: honeydew; }`